# TestContainers cannot connect to opened ports

Tags: testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

In one of my tests using testcontainers, the container failed to start and the log is:

```
  [ERROR] 17:31:38,814 [Test worker] 1.1]. - Could not start container
     org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [49154, 49155, 49156, 49157] should be listening)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:90) ~[testcontainers-1.16.2.jar:?]
```

However, when I notice it took so long to start up the container, I looked at the container status:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                                                     NAMES
a9b52c87cf48   corda-four-nodes:0.1.1      "/bin/bash runnodes.…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   10030-10033/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49157->10010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49156->10011/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49155->10012/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->10013/tcp   nice_merkle
f1de539585cd   testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3   "/app"                   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:49153->8080/tcp                                                                                                   testcontainers-ryuk-69c9e72d-040b-4625-a82e-dbaf7d0a1cec
```

So clearly ports `10010-10013` have been mapped to `49154-49157`, and using `netcat`, these ports are reachable, but why did the error occur and the container cannot be started?

Container definition:

```java
    @Container
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static GenericContainer network = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse(IMAGE_NAME))
            .withFileSystemBind(getCordappPath(), "/nodes/Notary/cordapps", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
            .withFileSystemBind(getCordappPath(), "/nodes/PartyA/cordapps", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
            .withFileSystemBind(getCordappPath(), "/nodes/PartyB/cordapps", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
            .withFileSystemBind(getCordappPath(), "/nodes/PartyC/cordapps", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
            .withExposedPorts(10010, 10011, 10012, 10013)
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(180));
```

(The binding works correctly)

Comment: Can you share the container setup from your Java test?

Comment: @rieckpil sure, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?